# docker-compose ignores `configs:` section

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've got a docker-compose service definition with a configs section as follows:

```
# api.yml file
version: '3.3'

services:
  api:
    ...
    configs:
      - source: api_config
        target: /env.cfg

configs:
  api_config:
  file: ./config/my.cfg
```

When I use this file to drive a swarm, i.e. I deploy it with `docker stack deploy ...` the config file is properly provided into the running containers.

However, when I try to run a local version of the api via `docker-compose -f api.yml up` I get a startup failure complaining of my api service that it can't find its config. (NB: docker-compose itself doesn't report any errors.)

Are `configs` sections not supported with plain `docker-compose` usage?

The docs don't explicitly say so although some wording seems to indicate this is for stacks only:

> Note: The config must already exist or be defined in the top-level configs configuration of this stack file, or stack deployment will fail.

Comment: How did you handle it? There is any workaround to use Docker Configs section from Swarm in Docker Compose? Do you have to modify your local `yml` file every time?

Comment: It's been a while but IIRC I think I just made my local environment a single node swarm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Configs and secrets are implemented using the embedded raft key value store provided by swarm mode. Those features aren't available to containers not running as part of swarm mode yet, so they will be ignored by docker-compose.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/#about-configs

> Note: Docker configs are only available to swarm services, not to standalone containers. To use this feature, consider adapting your container to run as a service with a scale of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `configs` is not supported in `docker compose` according to this [github issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5110). I've just wasted my time trying it after reading the docs. You need to write a custom Dockerfile to build the config file.

Comment: `Server Version: 20.10.23` seems support `configs` now